# __init__.robot file in Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a code that will assign a global variable so all tests then can use this global variable. I created a file `__init__.robot` in the tests folder and in the settings part:

```
*** Settings ***
Test Setup   Assign a global variable 

*** keywords ***
Assign a global variable 
  set a global variable ${test} Hello
```

Now when I run my other tests, it seems this file does not run before any test
and it does not find ${test}

My Question: Anyone knows how to use **init**.robot file that will run before all tests?

Thanks

Comment: How are you running robot? the `__init__.robot` file will only run if you pass the folder name to robot on the command line.

Comment: I read I should put it inside the tests folder, since it is __init__.robot syntax, it will be run automatically before all tests?

Answer (score 3):

First of all your `Set Variable` syntax is faulty. Use this instead

```
Assign a Global Variable
    Set Global Variable    ${test}    Hello
```

It's of course case-insensitive but as you can see, there is no additional `a` and there must be *at least* two empty spaces between the keyword and arguments as well as between each given argument. This would however throw an error so if you are not facing that, you have something else wrong as well.

Since you have not provided information on how you are actually executing the test suite it's not possible to give a simple answer. However, in order for the `__init__.robot` to be executed first, you need to have two pre-requisites correctly.

1. The `__init__.robot` must be either in the same folder or in folder above the directory where the actual test suite file is. Consider a rough hierarchy scetch:

```
| --TestSuite_0.robot
| --TestSuites
    |
    | --__init__.robot
    | --TestSuite_1.robot
    | --SomeFolder
        |
        | --TestSuite_2.robot
```

Now the `TestSuite_0.robot` will not use the `__init__.robot` file at all, but both 1 and 2 will do if you have the second requirement down.

2. Execute test from folder instead of the test suite directly, this will enable the initialization file to be found, if you wish to limit the number of tests or test suites you run, use the `-t` and `-s` parameters.

For example you could run the suite 1 with the initialization with following
`robot -s 'TestSuite_1' path\to\TestSuites`

This way the `__init__.robot` is found first and only then the actual test suite is being launched.

Finally, the `Test Setup` only applies per test. If you wish to actually have a global variable, you may want to take a look into [Resource Files](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#resource-files) instead.

Comment: I have exactly the same hierarchy as you scetched. Running TestSuite_1 works fine. But when running TestSuite_2, suite setup and teardown defined in init do not apply. `robot -s 'TestSuite_2' SomeFolder/`. How to run TestSuite_2 so that init file is applied?

Comment: @FrumdaGrayforce You'll need to start the execution from the directory where the ``__init__.robot`` is located. In this case the correct command would be  ``robot -s 'TestSuite_2' TestSuites/``.